# Como obtener la clase del menú en Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, class

Necesito obtener la clase CSS opcional del menú de wordpress.
Quiero obtener la clase para ponerle iconos al menú

[image: Clase desde el panel de control de wordpress]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! Te recomiendo que en lugar de una foto con el codigo pongas el codigo en formato texto asi tu pregunta queda mucho mejor. Un saludo :)

Comment: Una forma de obtener los .css del tema que tengas configurado es entrando en el servidor del host. Si por ejemplo utilizas hostinger, puedes navegar de forma intuitiva por el repositorio de archivos y modificar aquí a tu gusto los .css, o incluir los tuyos propios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos si estas haciendo un menú personalizado puedes usar esta linea

`$class = esc_attr( implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $menu_item->classes ), $menu_item) ) );`

Esto lo que hace es leer la clase css que le das al item.

Comment: Perfecto compañero. Es exactamente lo que necesitaba. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

No es eso exactamente lo que necesito.
Lo que busco es reemplazar una clase del array -> 'before' -> %1$s para mostrar iconos.
Esta sería la sentencia de código, lo que necesito sería el filtro o la función que reemplaza %1$s

```
wp_nav_menu( array (
                    'theme_location'=> 'menu-1',
                    'menu_id'       => 'primary-menu',
                    'menu_class'    => 'right',
                    'before'        => '<i class="%1$s">',
                    'after'         => '</i>',
                ) );
```

Siendo el resultado

```
<i class="clase"><a href="#">Link</a></i>
```

Siendo el resultado final un menu con iconos 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]